# How to add new columns to nested lists using lapply via a string recognition function

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am attempting use a %in% function to add particular columns to data frames nested within a list of lists. Below is a toy example of my data.

dput(head(list)):

```
 list(FEB_games = list(GAME1 = structure(list(GAME1_Class = c("paladin", 
"fighter", "wizard", "sorcerer", "rouge"), GAME1_Race = c("human", 
"elf", "orc", "human", "gnome"), GAME1_Alignment = c("NE", "CG", 
"CE", "NN", "LG"), GAME1_Level = c(6, 7, 6, 7, 7), GAME1_Alive = c("y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y")), row.names = c("m.Stan", "m.Kenny", "m.Cartman", 
"m.Kyle", "m.Butters"), class = "data.frame"), GAME2 = structure(list(
GAME2_Class = c("wizard", "cleric", "monk", "bard"), GAME2_Race = c("half-elf", 
"elf", "human", "dwarf"), GAME2_Alignment = c("CG", "CE", 
"NN", "LG"), GAME2_Level = c(5, 5, 5, 5), GAME2_Alive = c("y", 
"y", "y", "y")), row.names = c("m.Kenny", "m.Cartman", "m.Kyle", 
"m.Butters"), class = "data.frame")), MAR_games = list(GAME3 = structure(list(
GAME3_Class = c("cleric", "barbarian", "warlock", "monk"), 
GAME3_Race = c("elf", "half-elf", "elf", "dwarf"), GAME3_Alignment = c("LG", 
"LG", "CE", "LG"), GAME3_Level = c(1, 1, 1, 1), GAME3_Alive = c("y", 
"y", "y", "y")), row.names = c("l.Stan", "l.Kenny", "l.Cartman", 
"l.Butters"), class = "data.frame"), GAME4 = structure(list(GAME4_Class = c("fighter", 
"wizard", "sorcerer", "rouge"), GAME4_Race = c("half-elf", "elf", 
"human", "dwarf"), GAME4_Alignment = c("CG", "CE", "LN", "LG"
), GAME4_Level = c(5, 5, 5, 5), GAME4_Alive = c("y", "y", "y", 
"y")), row.names = c("l.Kenny", "l.Cartman", "l.Kyle", "l.Butters"), class = "data.frame")))
```

---

I have two different sets of columns (data frames) to add. Feb_detentions to Feb_games and Mar_detentions to Mar_games.

dput(head(Feb_detentions)):

```
structure(list(Pupil = c("m.Stan", "m.Stan", "m.Kenny", "m.Cartman", 
"m.Kyle", "Butters"), Detention = c("y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput(head(Mar_detentions)):

```
structure(list(Pupil = c("l.Stan", "l.Kenny", "l.Cartman", "l.Kyle"), 
Detention = c("n", "y", "y", "n")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

I have been successful in using these steps to add the columns of interest to a data frame (not nested in a list). Duplicates had to be removed the function, I was not able to do this inside the function.

Feb_detentions[! duplicated(Feb_detentions$Pupil),] -> Feb_detentions_dup

```
addDetentions <- function(df, df_namecol, detentions,  detention_namecol){
df[which(df_namecol %in% detention_namecol == T),] -> df_v1
detentions[which(detention_namecol %in% df_namecol == T),] -> det_v1
cbind(df_v1, det_v1) -> df_edit
return(df_edit)
}

addDetentions(df = GAME1, df_namecol = rownames(GAME1),
          detentions = Feb_detentions_dup, detention_namecol = Feb_detentions_dup$Pupil) -> output
```

---

dput(head(output)):

```
structure(list(GAME1_Class = c("paladin", "fighter", "wizard", 
"sorcerer", "rouge"), GAME1_Race = c("human", "elf", "orc", "human", 
"gnome"), GAME1_Alignment = c("NE", "CG", "CE", "NN", "LG"), 
GAME1_Level = c(6, 7, 6, 7, 7), GAME1_Alive = c("y", "y", 
"y", "y", "y"), Pupil = c("m.Stan", "m.Kenny", "m.Cartman", "m.Kyle", 
"m.Butters"), Detention = c("y", "y", "n", "n", "y")), row.names =  c("m.Stan", "m.Kenny", "m.Cartman", "m.Kyle", "m.Butters"), class = "data.frame")
```

---

I would like to perform this function (or something else that works) to the entire list. But since there are two different set of columns to add to two different nested lists in a single list I am a bit stuck.

```
lapply(Chars_alive, function(x) {addDetentions(x, rownames(x), Feb_detentions, Feb_detentions$Pupil)})
```

Any help would be appreciated here.

---

Comment: Do you need `Map(function(x, y) lapply(x, function(dat) {dat$Pupil <- row.names(dat); merge(dat, y)}), lst1, list(Feb_detentions, Mar_detentions))`

Comment: @akrun Think this worked very well, thanks. Can I ask what the x and y do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do a `merge` between the nested data.frames of the `list` and a corresponding `list` created in the same order as the names (month names of the first `list`).  `Map` does the looping through the corresponding `list` elements

```
Map(function(x, y) 
   # x is the first list which is a nested one
   # so loop through it
   lapply(x, function(dat) {
      # create a Pupil column from the row names
      dat$Pupil <- row.names(dat)
      # merge with the corresponding 'detentions' dataset
      merge(dat, y)
      }),
      # first list, created list
      lst1, list(Feb_detentions, Mar_detentions))
```

---

With `tidyverse`, this can be done using `map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(lst1, list(Feb_detentions, Mar_detentions),
       ~ {
         ydat <- .y
         map(.x, ~ .x %>%
                    rownames_to_column("Pupil") %>% 
                    inner_join(ydat))
         })
```

#### Update

If we need to only update the second nested `list` from the 'lst1', just extract that `list` element and do the `merge`

```
Map(function(x, y)  x[[2]] <- {
      x[[2]]$Pupil <- row.names(x[[2]])
     merge(x[[2]], y)
      x
      }, lst1, list(Feb_detentions, Mar_detentions))
```

Comment: Both functions worked on my toy data set but on my real data it added the new columns to the second list but not the first. I think this is because the row.names in my two nested lists are different. Will edit the question so this is more clear.

Comment: @Krutik In that case, you don't need the second loop i.e. `lapply` or `map` instead do the `x[[2]] <- {x[[2]]$Pupil <- row.names(x[[2]]); merge(x[[2]], y)}`